# fcitx often gives tty (WARN-PID# x11selection.c:309) Selection is too long

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, fcitx

I do not remember this has been since when. Suddenly, since a few days ago or a week, this message came upon the Terminal which didn't do anything at the moment.

Perhaps this might be something with `xclip`, because I think in my memory, I started to see the message after installing the `xclip` package.

And I do not know what caused, just it gives me an awkward feeling.

Answer (score 1):

The error that I got was a pile of:

`(WARN-28511 x11selection.c:309) Selection is too long.`

Thanks for the careful observation -- the message came upon the Terminal is indeed from `fcitx`:

https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx/blob/15046e8b9f2c3b4ac1128d5b0cfeb65bf5ccec87/src/module/x11/x11selection.c#L308-L309

I'll get it whenever my x11 selection string is too long, like when the mouse-selection is too large.

Since I started `fcitx` myself from the command line, I fixed the issue simply by starting `fcitx` with:

`fcitx 2>/dev/null`

**PS.**

If you have already started fcitx, then killing it alone will result in double `dbus-daemon` instances when starting `fcitx` again. However, this is why I'm adding this PS, killing `dbus-daemon` will also kill all Xapps that started *after* `dbus-daemon` was started, including chrome & telegram-desktop. It's not a big deal, just be prepared. So a full restart would be:

```
pkill fcitx
pkill dbus-daemon
fcitx 2>/dev/null
```